# Disable Web Search on Windows 10 Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I want to know how to disable Web Search on the Windows 10 Start Menu. I still want to be able to search Apps, Programs and Files, but I think that searching the web is really bogging it down, and I only search the web with my Browser anyways.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, the approach listed in [magicandre1981's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1009722/21922) no longer works. In fact, it's almost like Microsoft is fighting an arms race with users, progressively making it harder and harder to disable this feature.

[This page](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/remove-disable-web-search-from-windows-10/) says you can disable this via `gpedit.exe`, but doing that doesn't completely disable it.

[This page](https://www.ghacks.net/2015/06/23/how-to-disable-web-search-in-windows-10s-start-menu/) lists a series of different ways (including `gpedit.exe` and `regedit.exe`) which would all seem to have worked at *some* stage, but now the only one that completely shuts it down is the last one: Fighting it at the Windows Firewall level. And you have to read the fine print of that page to see that originally you blocked outbound connections from a predefined rule called "Search" but that rule doesn't exist anymore and you have to look for the "Cortana" rule instead. So:

1. In the search box, type **firewall** and then select Windows Defender Firewall from the resulting list
2. Click **Advanced Settings**
3. Click **Outbound Rules** on the left-hand side
4. Click the **Name** header to sort the rules alphabetically
5. Depending on your build of Windows 10, find either the **Search** or **Cortana** rules. (In my case, there were two **Cortana** rules.)
6. Click the rule (**Search** or **Cortana**).
7. On the right-hand side, click **Properties**
8. In the resulting dialog box, under **Action**, choose **Block the connection**

Of course, if you block Cortana, Cortana can't search the web for you anymore even when you specifically want it to.

Stupid Microsoft. Does it not occur to them that if people want to turn off search-the-web-from-the-search-box, that's their business?! Should have left the blasted setting there.

Answer (score 3):

## Windows 10 21H1

The following approach removed the Web tab from the Start Menu search.

Create and execute a `.reg` file with the following contents.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer]
"DisableSearchBoxSuggestions"=dword:00000001
```

Or, manually:

1. Open Registry Editor, (Type `regedit` in Start Menu or in the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> window).
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows`.
3. Right click on `Windows` > `New` > `Key` and create a key with name `Explorer`.
4. Right click on `Explorer` > `New` > `DWORD (32-bit) value` and create a value with name `DisableSearchBoxSuggestions` and data `1`.

Reboot or restart the `explorer.exe` process. To restart the process, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> > `More details` below > `Details` tab > find and select `explorer.exe` > hit <kbd>Del</kbd> and confirm that.

Comment: Still works today (Win10) and changes it from the menu that has tabs for Apps, Web, etc into a much simpler search list.

Comment: This worked for me on Win11 23H2, in conjunction with the `gpedit` changes suggested by @t-j-crowder, which alone did not remove web results.

Answer (score 2):

Open the search setting (this little gear symbol in search) a[nd in the option disable](http://www.howtogeek.com/224159/how-to-disable-bing-in-the-windows-10-start-menu/) the option "Search online and include web results"

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How were you able to find it? What keywords did you use?

Comment: I did a google search for "disable web results in windows 10 search" and found this howtogeek guide.

Comment: Does it work for you? Were you able to turn off the setting?

Answer (score 2):

### Spring 2020 Update

Block **Windows Search** in Windows Defender Firewall.
(Blocking *Cortana* and/or *Search* does not disable Web Search.)

1. Click **Start** and scroll down to click on **Windows Security**
2. Click **Advanced Settings**
3. Click **Outbound Rules** on the left-hand side
4. Click the **Name** header to sort the rules alphabetically
5. Click **Windows Search**
6. On the right-hand side, click **Properties**
7. In the resulting dialog box, under **Action**, choose **Block the connection**
8. Click **Apply**. Changes are immediate.

Please comment if you know how to clear the search cache.

Comment: Thanks. Search cache - Try searching your settings for `clear history`, two of the results led to the same page with some relevant privacy switches and a "clear history" button. Pressing that button didn't take effect for me until after a restart.