# Where is the option to disable web search in windows 10 start menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

Windows 10 seems to have an annoying bug where it tries to do a web search every time I type something in the start menu search bar

It's nice that it searches through the computer to try and find the relevant programs or settings, but I do not want it to search the internet and slow down the computer at all

[This](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-bing-search-windows-10-start-menu), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1009708/disable-web-search-on-windows-10-start-menu), [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-web-searches-in-start-menu/e6a2c632-f1dc-4c41-8695-a6b1740293f0) and most other solutions I have been able to find online all suggest to find a cortana setting where there is an option to block web search on the start menu but it doesn't seem to exist anymore. How do I block this annoying feature on Windows 10?  I am using Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

[This](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/disable-web-searches-in-start-menu/e6a2c632-f1dc-4c41-8695-a6b1740293f0) says there is a registry edit that should disable it, but I haven't tried it yet and would prefer a solution that doesn't involve registry editing. Has anyone here tried this registry hack and is it safe?

Comment: Edit your question to include what version of Windows 10 you are using.  You should also include what cumulative update you have most recently installed

Comment: It says windows 10 pro 64 bit in the question. The guy who set it up for me downloaded a bunch of updates about a week ago so I guess everything is the latest.

Comment: I am asking for which version of Windows 10.  There are currently 6 different versions of Windows 10.  What version you are, and knowing what cumulative update you have installed, is critical to answering this question due to your desire to disable web search on Windows 10.  How you approach this problem on a version like 1607 is entirely different compared to 1903.  So please answer the question by editing the information into your question.  **Your links only apply to versions from before version 1809 which is the reason they didn't work.**

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1196618/how-to-disable-internet-search-results-in-start-menu-post-creators-update

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using V1903, open Search and in the Window that comes up, you can search for what you wish. You can enhance Search Settings (click on ... to see these) but you cannot modify Search window to exclude Web so far as I know.

I use Search a lot and just click on Apps, or Documents as I need. Works well

[image]

Comment: what is V1903? I need to disable web search completely on the start menu. It unnecessarily slows things down. If I wanted to search the internet I would use a browser

Comment: V1903 is the current version of Windows. I looked at the next version on a different machine and the search works the same way. Clicking on Documents adheres to your Indexing settings and is very fast.

Comment: I added a picture so you can see where to click to limit the search